# How can I add a group inside /etc/group of a target root file system?

Tags: makefile, filesystems, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, root

I am cross-compiling target RFS from a makefile which is executing on a host machine? Is there any specific usage of groupadd command that i should know? Also do I need to use groupadd from host linux machine or the target's embedded version of groupadd? How to specify within groupadd command to add group in the target RFS and not in the host machine. I am new to this.
example :
**/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 1111 test_gp**
I need to create 1111 inside a specific path where rfs is getting compiled,say /home/arm_build/rfs/
and then add a user under it

**/usr/sbin/useradd -g test_gp -m -d /home/test_gp -p l.cjpassword -s /bin/bash -c "A test group" test_gp**

what will be the equivalent command as I see there is no option to provide path in groupadd it just takes a number as gid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options:

- `/etc/group` is nothing but a text file,
  so you can create it manually or from your own scripts
- according to the manpage, `groupadd --root <DIR>` will modify files under
  `<DIR>`, so you can point it to the directory where you are building your
  root filesystem
- don't reinvent the wheel and use an existing buildsystem:
  Buildroot and Yocto are the mostly used ones and of course they handle
  group creation

Comment: I edited my comment and added the command just for more clarity.

Comment: I got the groupadd to work. Thanks.. Would useradd and chown commands also work on and for a changed root dir?

Comment: You mean using `chroot`? Well, it would work, but it's more complex if you are corss-compiling because you need either to put a temporary native useradd on the cross rootfs or to run the cross-built useradd with qemu.

Comment: I am getting a FAIL_DELAY on executing the useadd command and although groupadd does work creating a group inside the RFS, the useradd does not do so. Also I do not see an option under chown that could work for a target RFS from the host. I am clueless here and looking for alternatives :)

Comment: Can you explain better what error you have with `useradd`? Please report a complete log with the command you issue, the output you get and any detail that might help understanding.

Comment: `chown` must be called inside chroot, at least if you want to set root as the owner of a file in your root filesystem without being root on your development host.